# Other than using `split`, is there a way around the Apache 2.0 maximum file size limit of 2GB?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, files, iso

I have some ISOs that need to be available across a WAN, so we are using an http server to host them (allows for non-authenticated, read-only access (beyond being on the VPN) to the data store).

The server the ISOs reside on is running CentOS 4, and Apache 2.0.58.

Is there a way around the 2GB filesize limit with Apache 2.0 without using the `split` utility to chunk the ISOs down to a less-than-2GB size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upgrade the Apache install to 2.2.x then larger files should work by default (as 2.2 uses 64 bit file position offsets by default if supported by the OS).

I believe similar support is possible directly in Apache 2.0.x, at least in later minor versions there-of, but generally only if you compile your own custom version.

Comment: Thanks, David - that was what I was afraid I'd hear... unfortunately, upgrading is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Would it be possible to do you own compile of the Apache package? I know Debian has good support for grabbing a package's source (with their back-ported patches), compiling with different options, and making your own package that will work in place their standard one - I'm sire CentOS (being based on RHEL) will have similar support in its package management arrangement. Obviously the compiling and testing must be done on another (perhaps virtual) machine, and it isn't a hands-free-simple process, but it might be a useful stop-gap for you.